# Xamarin.MAC Activity logger (keyboard, mouse, active window)

Tags: c#, macos, xamarin, xamarin.mac

I recently wrote a simple c# application that run on windows and logs user activity (keyboard, mouse and active window). Now It's required for the application to run on MAC. So I am thinking of purchasing a xamarin subscription to make my application cross platform compatible.

So my question is will xamarin.mac api and OSX security support this features and let me achieve this goal or should I forget about xamarin and develop a separate OSX application?

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin.Mac exposes the underlying Cocoa APIs, but does't have 100% API coverage. I'd first do some research to see of Cocoa has APIs exposed to do what you want (if there is any). Then you can download the trial and see if what you need is exposed.